Помогите с решением задачи новичку.(Python)
Суммирование миллиона чисел: создайте список чисел от 1 до 1 000 000, затем воспользуйтесь функциями min() и max() и убедитесь в том, что список действительно начинается с 1 и заканчивается 1 000 000. Вызовите функцию sum() и посмотрите, насколько быстро Python сможет просуммировать миллион чисел.

Ну хоть книжку какую откройте...

Вам же по шагам прямо всё расписано, легкое же задание. Кстати, по времени суммирование примерно столько же занимает, сколько создание этого списка.

Надеюсь у Вас были попытки решения задачи
numbers = list(range(1, 1000001))

minimum = min(numbers)
maximum = max(numbers)

print(f"Минимальное значение: {minimum}")
print(f"Максимальное значение: {maximum}")

import time

start_time = time.time()
total_sum = sum(numbers)
end_time = time.time()

print(f"Сумма чисел: {total_sum}")
print(f"Время выполнения: {end_time - start_time:.6f} секунд")


Большое спасибо.

Зря вы это делаете. Я тоже иногда нарушаю правила и отвечаю на учебные вопросы даже если спрашивающий ничего не сделал сам. Но я оправдываюсь тем что я отвечаю на интересные или сложные вопросы. Здесь, конечно, не такая ситуация. И обратите внимание что ТС сказал вам спасибо, но ни галочку не поставил, ни плюсик. Такая обратная связь.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Часто просто закрываю на это глаза, когда вижу "новичков", но правда в ваших словах есть:)
